# Objective-C: How to store typedef enum in a plist?

Tags: objective-c, plist, typedef

Plists seem to have a limited number of data types that you can enter in. However, I know there are loopholes, such as storing an int as a Number and then using [x integerValue] to set it back to an int. Is there a similar workaround for storing typedef enums in a property list?

Since they are really just ints, is there some way to store them as Numbers and then casting them as their typedef?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to store the raw enum integer values and then load them out again as integers. Once you've loaded them out again as `NSNumbers` you can then use `[num intValue]` to get the integer. Then you can compare it to your enum, for example:

```
intRep = [loadedNumber intValue];
if (intRep == MY_ENUM_CONSTANT) {
    // Do something...
}
// ... etc.
```

To store the value `"MY_ENUM_CONSTANT"` as a string inside the plist doesn't have any meaning - and reverse engineering it if `-isEqualToString` is definitely fighting the system. If you need more flexibility though you may be able to store binary data objects inside the plist, this is probably overdoing it a bit for what you need though.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to translate them into a format suitable for plist, you can use the integer value is the simplest and use NSNumber, but you can alternatively write a couple of functions to convert to and from a string value. If you use the default integers for for enum, 0, 1, 2 etc. You can then use the enum as an index into an array of string, to get from string back to enum/int, use a for loop thru your string array and return the matching index.